# Calculating sine function using Monad.Writer

Tags: haskell

I have some implementation of `sin` function using Taylor Series. In it I'm using `map` like that:

```
sin' x = sum $ map (\n -> term x n) [0..50]
    where term x n = (x^pw / fromIntegral (fact pw))*(-1)^n
          pw = 2*n+1
```

But how can I «save» intermediate values in Writer's log (using `tell`)? Do I have to rewrite my function using recursion calls? I can't understand how to get these intermediate values without recursion

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to save?  Each value of `term x n`?  Also, you're not using list comprehension, you're using `map`, and it could more simply written as `sum $ map (term x) [0..50]`.  If it were list comprehension, it'd be like `sum [term x n | n <- [0..50]]`, then `|` and `<-` make it list comprehension.

Comment: Honestly, if you just want intermediate values, I'd use `scanl` instead of complicated `Writer` stuff.

Comment: If you want all the terms, don't do the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're asking for, but it's the only useful way to employ `Writer` here that I can think of.

The problem with such a naïve Taylor-series implemention is that you keep calculating the power and factorial over and over again, when really it would be much more efficient to do it incrementally. The recurrence is this:

```
      term' x pw ≡ - x^2 * term' x (pw-2) / fromIntegral pw
```

Of course, you don't want to recompute that for each summand, rather you want to sum the terms as you go. That's where the writer comes in; we need of course `Writer (Sum Double)`.

```
      procTerms :: Double -> Int -> Writer (Sum Double) Double
      procTerms x 1 = tell (Sum x) >> return x
      procTerms x pw = do
         newterm <- fmap (* (- x^2 / fromIntegral pw)) $ term' x (pw-2)
         tell $ Sum newterm
         return newterm
```

We can't really get rid of the recursion here; a fixpoint with `mfix` wouldn't be useful since we can't get the back references out of the result.